# File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap error line #5

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap

Gemfile

```
group :assets do
  gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'
  gem 'sass-rails', '>= 3.2'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'
end
```

application.html.erb

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
   <head>
    <title>One Month Rails</title>
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", :media => "all" %>   #This line is the 1st line error.
```

application.js

```
 //= require bootstrap  #added this in.
```

styles.css.scss

```
 @import 'bootstrap';
 @import 'bootstrap-responsive';
```

Showing C:/Temp/demo/code/omrails/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb where line #5 raised:

File to import not found or unreadable: bootstrap.
Load paths:

> C:/Temp/demo/code/omrails/app/assets/images
>   C:/Temp/demo/code/omrails/app/assets/javascripts
>   C:/Temp/demo/code/omrails/app/assets/stylesheets
>   C:/Temp/demo/code/omrails/vendor/assets/javascripts
>   C:/Temp/demo/code/omrails/vendor/assets/stylesheets
>   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/turbolinks-2.3.0/lib/assets/javascripts   C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/jquery-rails-3.1.2/vendor/assets/javascripts
>   (in
>   C:/Temp/demo/code/omrails/app/assets/stylesheets/styles.css.scss:1)

I tried restarting rails server as all the other suggestions here posted. Still same problem.

Comment: What is this import you have on application.css.scss -> @import 'bootstrap-responsive'; ?

Comment: @import 'bootstrap-responsive' is actually in a new css file I created called styles.css.scss. All it does is import bootstrap and bootstrap responsive

Comment: Deleted the group: assets do in the gemfile and also deleted the import bootstrap responsive line. No more error messages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`bootstrap-responsive.css` (and related Sass/Less files) was part of Bootstrap v2 and was eliminated in Bootstrap v3 (because responsiveness became baked-in).

You're using Bootstrap v3 (per `gem 'bootstrap-sass', '~> 3.2.0'`), so you're trying to reference a nonexistent file, hence the error.